# Spring Boot - excluding some URLs when enforcing SSL with security.require-ssl=true

Tags: spring-boot

Since AWS health check uses HTTP, Spring Boot keeps redirecting health check requests to HTTPS counterparts, which AWS interprets as failing health check. Is there any way to exclude some URLs when enforcing SSL with security.require-ssl=true?